# MySQL INSERT into select * from with default timestamp column

Tags: mysql

This is simple problem, but I feel like there should be an elegant solution.  I have had a script which works by using this statement:

```
insert into table1 select * from table2 where pk = "'.$pk.'";
```

Recently I want to add a column to the end of `table1` which is a timestamp column with default value `now()`.  This generally works and I was expecting to not have to change the above statement, but if I add the new timestamp column, the above statement will fail with the following error:

> column count doesn't match value count

Comment: Please explain a bit more. Better exemplify your use case.

Comment: yeah accidentally pushed save

Comment: `insert into jobticket.flatdestroyed (col1,col2) select col1,col2,.....` So select the columns other than the timestamp on and insert into should have the columns other than the timestamp and if its set default as current timestamp it should do what you want.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty yes thank you I was hoping not to have to do that, but I can see that your solution will work.  Also sorry I just edited the Q, it is `table1` that I want to add the column to.  Only reason is there are like 100 columns... guess I'm just being lazy.

Comment: So you showed us the statement that works, but didn't show us the statement that didn't work? And you want help with the statement that didn't work? o.O

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is the same statement.  I guess the question wasn't clear but I was expecting to be able to add the column to table1 without having to change the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 solution for it, either specify your columns list

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2) select col1, col2  from table2 where pk = "'.$pk.'";
```

or

create same column in table1 to avoid column list in query

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, often happens that as soon as I ask my question here on stackoverflow I end up trying something that works.  I was able to alter the statement in the question to the following which works, although I lose the default functionality for the new column.  Since the last column is hard-coded in this case it still works the same way.

```
insert into table1 select *, now() from table2 where pk = "'.$pk.'";
```